# El controlador de mi proyecto no me muestra la vista de la carpeta templates. Muestra error 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, vscode, maven, controller

estoy utilizando vs code studio por primera vez y a la hora de crear un proyecto de java con spring boot y maven al utilizar un controller no me devuelve la vista del archivo template. Al lanzar la aplicación me devuelve un error 404. El código es el siguiente:

**El controlador:**

```
package com.pruebaspr.pruebaspring.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**el archivo pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pruebaspr</groupId>
    <artifactId>prueba-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>prueba-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
```

He probado lanzarlo en otro puerto, reiniciar el ordenador y no ha tenido resultados, sigue mostrando el error 404

Comment: y tu application.properties o application.yaml?